# WebSocket chat application not displaying sent message, but refreshing the page instead

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, django-channels, asgi

I was building a web app to send messages using django.I could not Figure out why this part of the code isnt working,When I type the message and hit send, It just refreshes the page without displaying the message.I even tried inspecting the code in chrome dev tools,but nothing has been displayed on the console suggesting that the javascript code isnt working.

`

```
const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-roomname').textContent);
const userName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-username').textContent);

let url = 'ws://${window.location.host}/ws/${roomName}/'
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(url);

chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log('onclose')
}

chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    if (data.message) {
        document.querySelector('#chat-messages').innerHTML += ('<b>' + data.username + '</b>: ' + data.message + '<br>');
    } else {
        alert('The message was empty!')
    }

    scrollToBottom();
};

document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
    }
};

document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
    const message = messageInputDom.value;

    console.log({
        'message': message,
        'username': userName,
        'room': roomName
    })

    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
        'message': message,
        'username': userName,
        'room': roomName
    }));

    messageInputDom.value = '';

    return false
};

/**
* A function for finding the messages element, and scroll to the bottom of it.
*/
function scrollToBottom() {
    let objDiv = document.getElementById("chat-messages");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}

// Add this below the function to trigger the scroll on load.
scrollToBottom();`
```

I expect it to display the message when you type a message and hit the send button!,How do I fix this.

Comment: Can you provide **HTML** code related to your question